# Pause function not working properly as the script keeps running

Tags: autohotkey

I wrote a ahk script, I want to pause the script when I press F7. Yet the script keeps on running and w and left click keeps getting pressed.

How can I modify so pressing f7 pauses the script and f8 resumes the script? Thanks

```
F8::
Loop
    send {w down}{click down}
return

F7::pause


esc:: ExitApp
```

Comment: You have misunderstood what Pause does. Pause will pause *the current thread*, not the entire script. Each time you fire a hockey, it will start a new thread to handle that hotkey before going back to doing what it was previously doing. By using Pause on F7, you just pause the F7 handler thread and other reads will continue like you've observed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one follows or replies to this question anymore, I might as well answer it myself. The key to resume is not to pause at the first point.

```
F8::SetTimer, F8 Up, 50
F8 Up::Send, {w down}{click down}
F7::SetTimer, F8 Up, Off
F7 Up::Send, {w up}{click up}
```

Using this timer, we set the function of W and click movement to trigger every 50 millisecond, the time does not really matter, since after first trigger, both are pushed down, and push it down again makes no effect.
F7 simply stops the trigger and pull the 2 bottons up.
By pressing F8 again, the trigger gets initialized again then we can just continue the cycle.

`Pause` is not ideal because it pauses the script, not the function

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to just release the held keys when the <kbd>F7</kbd> hotkey is pressed:

```
F8::
Loop
    send {w down}{click down}
return

F7::
send {w up}{click up}
pause
return

esc::ExitApp
```

Comment: Is there a way to resume the loop? For instance, I press F8, then F7, afterward, I want to resume again by pressing F8. How can I do that?